# Azure App Service File.ReadAllText returns File not found exception but file exist in that location

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have email templates as .cshtml file format in under the Content/Templates folder. We read that template using File.ReadAllText() then apply our model value then send that mail to the particular user. It works fine in locally hosted machine. When I host my asp.net mvc app in Azure App service file not found exception throws.

```
private string GetTemplateContent(string templatePath)
    {
        var templateContent = string.Empty;
        var path = GetAbsoluteTemplatePath(templatePath);

        try
        {
            templateContent = File.ReadAllText(Path.GetFullPath(path));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log exception
        }

        return templateContent;
    }
```

Path in Azure "D:\home\site\wwwroot\Content\Templates\ScheduleTemplate.cshtml"

I ensured file exist in that location.

Can you help me why this is happening?

Comment: can you share in info about what GetAbsoluteTemplatePath and Path.GetFullPath is return?

Comment: @JatinParmar 
templatePath = _"~/Content/Templates/ScheduleTemplate.cshtml"_
GetAbsoluteTemplatePath returns _D:\home\site\wwwroot\/Content/Templates/ScheduleTemplate.cshtm_l
Path.GetFullPath returns _D:\home\site\wwwroot\Content\Templates\ScheduleTemplate.cshtml_

Comment: Start by making sure it works correctly locally, by following [this document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Make-sure-site-correctly-deploys-locally)

Comment: According to exception, it indicates that file is not existed. You also could remote debug it and use kudu to check file again.

Comment: Ensured file exist @TomSun 
Same method have 3 lines of code, first one to read file next line write new file then 3rd read that newly written file 
Result : 3rd line file not found exception

Comment: @RajaduraiAzhagudurai  Have you referenced  [remote debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug)? `Ensured file exist` May I know how do you check that? Reading file from `D:\home\site\wwwroot\` is allowed from azure web app.

Comment: @TomSun using FileZilla to check file exist or not

Comment: I recommand that you could use  the hard code path to debug it.

Comment: @TomSun Yeah I tried that also
Sample Path Harcoded was D:\home\site\wwwroot\Content\Templates\ScheduleTemplate.cshtml

Comment: Also try to use the [kudu tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) to open 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\Content\Templates\ScheduleTemplate.cshtml ' with kudu console directly. Or you also could try other path (example:D:\home\site\wwwroot) with hard code.

Comment: @TomSun thanks for your response

Comment: @JatinParmar thanks man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Azure App service issue. From this [Thread](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/80283-app_plugins-path-error-on-azure-web-apps) we found the solution.
Add node in Application Setting

Key: WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE (all capitals)
Value: 0